# Different Facebook data in response based on auth token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm querying for public information available on a Facebook object. I receive a slightly different JSON response from Facebook depending on if I query with my application token or a token generated by graph explorer.

The query is as simple as requesting the following URL and using the appropriate access token in the URL https://graph.facebook.com/205732386217368?access_token=

Below are example responses when querying with the two different access tokens. The primary different is in the venue data.

**Response With Graph Explorer Access Token**

```
{
   "id": "205732386217368",
   "owner": {
      "category": "Non-profit organization",
      "name": "Australian Pain Management Association",
      "id": "223536391023779"
   },
   "name": "APMA Pain Support Group: Brisbane South",
   "description": "Second Tuesday of every month\n\nWe offer support, friendship, information, presentations and guest speakers. The groups are for everyone in the community living with pain (and their family members) and are FREE for APMA members. Non-members are asked to donate a gold coin at each meeting. \n\nThe purpose of the group is to offer positive support and encouragement, with a focus on the self-management of persistent pain.\n\nFor more information, contact Annette at 07 3359 2275 or Annette.ssr\u0040hotmail.com ",
   "start_time": "2013-08-13T10:30:00+1000",
   "end_time": "2013-08-13T12:00:00+1000",
   "timezone": "Australia/Brisbane",
   "is_date_only": false,
   "location": "Coorparoo RSL and Community Club",
   "venue": {
      "latitude": -27.494904155853,
      "longitude": 153.05662292452,
      "city": "Brisbane",
      "state": "QLD",
      "country": "Australia",
      "id": "203514029694703",
      "street": "45 Holdsworth Street, Coorparoo",
      "zip": "4151"
   },
   "privacy": "OPEN",
   "updated_time": "2013-06-25T01:43:27+0000"
}
```

**Response With Application Access Token**

```
{
   "id": "205732386217368",
   "owner": {
      "category": "Non-profit organization",
      "name": "Australian Pain Management Association",
      "id": "223536391023779"
   },
   "name": "APMA Pain Support Group: Brisbane South",
   "description": "Second Tuesday of every month\n\nWe offer support, friendship, information, presentations and guest speakers. The groups are for everyone in the community living with pain (and their family members) and are FREE for APMA members. Non-members are asked to donate a gold coin at each meeting. \n\nThe purpose of the group is to offer positive support and encouragement, with a focus on the self-management of persistent pain.\n\nFor more information, contact Annette at 07 3359 2275 or Annette.ssr\u0040hotmail.com ",
   "start_time": "2013-08-12T17:30:00",
   "end_time": "2013-08-12T19:00:00",
   "timezone": "Australia/Brisbane",
   "is_date_only": false,
   "location": "Coorparoo RSL and Community Club",
   "venue": {
      "name": "Coorparoo RSL and Community Club"
   },
   "privacy": "OPEN",
   "updated_time": "2013-06-25T01:43:27+0000"
}
```

Does anyone know why these two responses are different and how I can use my application token to receive the same response as I get with the graph explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The venue for that event has user restrictions on it.

Using the Facebook explorer you have the user context of yourself and you are over 21 or in the right location etc

User restriction doco can be seen here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/user-restrictions/

How I check for it is use a browser where I am not signed into facebook and go to the relevant page www.facebook.com/203514029694703 (your venue) and you will see without user context you cant see the page.  If you try and look at the same page with you logged in you will be able to see it as you do in the FB Explorer.